# How to apply a conditional after use groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I have a question with pandas,

I have the following code to group by State and sum the number of rows that in the String "Measure name" contains the word 'Death',

```
state_grp = df.groupby(['State'])
state_grp['Measure name'].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Death').sum())
```

**Result**:

| State | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| AK | 123 |
| DC | 24 |

but after obtaining the result i want to apply another conditional regarding the acronym of the state, for example if State contains the letter A multiply the 'Sum' by 2.

Final result:

| State | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| AK | 246 |
| DC | 24 |

I tried again with .apply(lambda x: ..) but I didn't get what I wanted,

I am new to pandas and I want to understand how to do it for study purposes.

Answer (score 1):

After the grouping/summing you can create a boolean mask using `.str.contains()` and then use this mask in `df.loc[]`:

```py
mask = df["State"].str.contains("A")
df.loc[mask, "Sum"] *= 2

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  State  Sum
0    AK  246
1    DC   24
```

---

EDIT: When the result of grouping/summing is series, you can construct the mask slightly differently:

```py
mask = df.index.str.contains("A")
df.loc[mask, "Sum"] *= 2

print(df)  # or print(df.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
       Sum
State     
AK     246
DC      24
```

Comment: maybe result is series

Comment: @PandaKim True, I've updated the answer with this possibility.